# Highlight recycler view items using StateListDrawables

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, statelistdrawable

I am trying to highlight recycler view items using state list drawables but my recycler view items never get highlighted. I have tried all SO post but none solve my problems.

This is my recyclerView:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:padding="@dimen/item_offset"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:scrollbars="none"
            android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
            android:listSelector="@drawable/highlight"
            android:foreground="@drawable/highlight"
             />
```

My single item code:

```
<RelativeLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:foreground="@drawable/highlight"
 android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
 android:padding="5dp">
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/grid_item_image"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:foreground="@drawable/highlight"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop">
</ImageView></RelativeLayout>
```

highlight.xml Selector code is:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@color/blue" android:state_pressed="true" />
<item android:drawable="@color/blue" android:state_selected="true" />
<item android:drawable="@color/blue" android:state_focused="true" />
<item android:drawable="@color/white" /></selector>
```

I have tried all possible solution. Somebody help me by sharing your valuable ideas?